# How to extend the Android MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns with custom columns?

Tags: android, image, exif, mediastore

#### Background

Currently I am working on a project that needs to deal with all images on Android phone. Android provided the [`MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html), together with [`ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) I can access meta data like longtitude and latitude of all images.

#### Question

What if I want to mark the photos with custom tags, and query photos with these tags, like, retrieve all photos tagged with "food"? What are the possible ways to do this?

#### Possible solution

1. For jpeg files, one can use [`ExifInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) to add attributes(the `setAttribute()` and `saveAttributes()` method). But according to the document:

   > This is expensive because it involves copying all the JPG data from one file to another and deleting the old file and renaming the other.

   Is it efficient enough when I have thousands of megapixel jpeg images?
2. I was considering building another database that syncs with the MediaStore database regularly. Better solutions?

Comment: what about storing the "file path" < AFAIK this will uniquely identify file in android file system> in your database with tag like "food"